# React: Create onClick HOC without using an additional <div />

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to avoid manually adding the `onClick` property to my custom components.

For that, I thought about a Higher Order Component named `WithClick` that would wrap my components with the integrated `onClick` property.

The problem I'm facing is that in order to wrap it, I have to use an additional `<div />` tag to access the event property. **And this tag is messing up my CSS.**

Example :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const WithClick = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class BaseComponent extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return BaseComponent
}

export default WithClick
```

---

The solution would be a hack, allowing to attach an onClick event to a `<React.Fragment />` tag or something similar.

I tried attaching ref to the child, but it doesn't work, I have to treat the ref prop in the child so there's no point doing that.

## Do you know a workaround ?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to avoid adding onClick?

Comment: I am curious what `WrappedComponent` looks like as I am unsure why you do not want to pass onClick down to it. You still want the user to click a visible object don't you? Whether it's a thumbnail, a button, etc and those things have a layout at the end of the day.

Comment: @georgeperry because it generates a lot of redundant code.

Comment: I have to agree with @BenHerbert, it doesn't seem sensible. the unnecessary code it generates in the DOM is relatives minute compared to the extra code you would need to write to get around this

Comment: @georgeperry The question is all about improving the code. Not about "Is it important to lost few seconds ?".

Comment: @Rémy Machado Iam a little confused but what I think is you want to wrap a component in `Fragment` and still pass onClick into `WrappedComponent`?

Comment: I do not see your point onclick has to be on a Dom element otherwise it will just be a prop to a component and that component would have to have a htlm elt with an onclick to use the passed prop. So I do not think that it is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I'm also a little skeptical of the need for this, I could see some specific case where you are adding the same handler to a lot of components and it would be necessary.

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode` is discouraged by the docs, and deprecated in strict mode. React.cloneElement is a better option.

```
const addClickToComponent = ({component}) => (
  React.cloneElement(component, {
    onClick: someComplicatedClickFunction,
  }
);

const ComponentWithClick = addClickToComponent(noClickComponent);
```

I usually make these wrapper components rather than HOC, and if you need to add a property to multiple children, you can do that.

```
const ClickWrapper = ({children}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {React.Children.map(children, child => (
      React.cloneElement(child, {
       onClick: someComplicatedClickFunction,
      )
     )
    }
  </React.Fragment>
 );

 // jsx

 <ClickWrapper>
   <ChildComponent />
   <ChildComponent />
   <ChildComponent />
 </ClickWrapper>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. My example with `onClick` wasn't really good, but you are right, there are similar cases. Thanks.

Comment: I use this often for style helper components for the UI library I maintain. for instance a `<Spacing>` component that adds appropriate margins for layout and passes an emotion.js style to wrapped components, so there are definitely  use cases. I could see the `onClick` case being useful if you were adding a hander that had a lot of boilerplate or something, it could neaten up your code a lot. Good luck!

Comment: Thank god for people who stick with the question in the title instead of going "don't do A, do B" route. For the OP, it might actually be better to do it differently but for many people who get here from google it is not . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrapper Component**

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
    render() { 
        return ( 
        <React.Fragment>
            <WrappedComponent />
        </React.Fragment>);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        //This will return the container of WrappedComponent
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).onclick = this.props.onClick
    }
}
export default Wrapper;
```

**Wrapped component**

```
class WrappedComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="wrappedComp"><span>I am wrapepd component</span></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It works. but as @JustH mentionned, ReactDom.findDOMNode() is deprecated.

Comment: @Rémy Machado I think i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

for those who don't want to mess up the CSS, using a span did the work for me.

Comment: Not a solution. "Span not messing up CSS" is not a rule but a specific. It works for you, but will not work for other, who need block element for example.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it may be handy to use `display: contents;` on a wrapper element, so additional wrapper with `onClick` will not break you code.