# React: Handling components that require a wrapper

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting into my first real React project, and I've ran into a common pattern I've had to deal with:

Oftentimes, some components require a wrapper. This can be seen, for example, with "FocusProvider" component. This component adds a wrapping div with functions attached to `onFocus` and `onBlur` and provides a context that says whether this component tree is in focus. Such a component looks something like this:

```
export const FocusProvider = ({ children }) => {
    // ... do stuff
    return (
        <div onBlur={ ... } onFocus={ ... }>
            <FocusContext.Provider value={ ... }>
                { children }
            </FocusContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The problem is that this div could mess with document flow / CSS. For example, if this is a child that needs to be a full height, or if its in a flexbox and needs to be flex-1.

One solution is to use a `renderWrapper` prop that is a function which accepts `{ attributes, children }` and returns the renderer. Using it mike look like this:

```
export const FocusProvider = ({ renderWrapper, children }) => {
    // ... do stuff
    return renderWrapper({
        attributes: {
            onFocus: ...,
            onBlur: ...,
        },
        children: (
            <FocusContext.Provider value={ ... }>
                { children }
            </FocusContext.Provider>
        ),
    });
};
```

But that quickly becomes annoying to actually use, as it's a bit cumbersome.

Is there a better solution?

Thanks,

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521354/react-create-onclick-hoc-without-using-an-additional-div